# UIScrollView works perfect in new project but did not scroll in xib based project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I am facing a weird issue, scenario is I am working some other's code and there is `viewController` for profile and there are `textfields` in `viewController`.. Let me explain briefly the hierarchy of `viewController`

**View 
-UIScrollView
 -TextFields (A lot of) 
 -UIButtons**

Issue is when I drag finger on `UITextfield` the `scrollView` do not scroll and if I drag other then `Textfields` view or empty view and even on `UItextView` the scroll works.

More I have created a new project in Xcode 7.3 and copy `scrollView` from the actual project I am working to new Project and enabled the property `DelaysContent` in `ScrollView` and it's working perfectly even if I dragged on `textfield` view..

Can someone help me regarding this what should I do.?

Answer (score 1):

I think If you create textField programmatically, you would not have added to ScrollView.So add to scrollView.

```
[viewTextField addSubview:textField];
[scrollView addSubview:viewTextField];
```

Then content size for scroll view is important

```
CGSize contentSize = scrollView.frame.size;
contentSize.height = 500; //Please set your required height
[scrollView setContentSize:contentSize];
```

Before that you have to set the delaysContentTouches and canCancelContentTouches to YES or NO depends on the below suggestion.

[UIScrollView with Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650437/uiscrollview-with-uibuttons-how-to-recreate-springboard)

[Adding Button to ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354815/iphone-adding-button-to-scrollview-makes-button-inaccessible-to-interaction)